# Basic JSON question

Tags: iphone, json

I know it might sound silly but how do I determine a website supports JSON?
I know what/how JSON use for a long time, but I do not know how could I technically know whether a
server has json support. Do I need to manually request json file to check whether it suppports or not?
Any comment would be appreciated !

Comment: Be more specific. Are you trying to use an API?

Comment: For instance, I want get JSON Ojbect from a website, but I don't know whether it supports JSON format or not. My question was "How do you know a website support JSON format of content"..

Comment: or for basic concepts, you can go for this useful and genuine link - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLc7STlqyZm1rd7UI6xV0lNUvVXFmRjxSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) "Websites" don't really serve up JSON; the notation syntax isn't really meant for page rendering, it's made for data transmission.

(2) What oftentimes serves up JSON are APIs (like those of [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com) and [StackExchange](http://stackapps.com)). These APIs usually use HTTP GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods to interact with services they provide, and (sometimes optionally) transmit the bulk of the payload data in JSON format.

(3) It doesn't really make sense to ask where to get JSON. If you'd simply like to play with some JSON for educational purposes, Python, PHP, Javascript, etc. all have great built-in support. What you ought to be looking for are the services that you'd like to utilize, and whether or not they support JSON. If the service is new, or popular, and has relatively good API support, odds are it will work with JSON.

Comment: What you said is basically web server supports JSON to transmit data via HTTP request, thats what I meant to ask..

Answer (score 2):

You can check what is the content type of server response, usually this is

```
application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, JOSN is just a format, like XML. You can create JSON page by hand, or use easy functions in a lot of the major coding languages.

Example: PHP does this easily with json_encode(String) json_decode(String). So, as far as my knowledge goes, every server / website can support JSON, though some might not have the updated PHP or whatever coding language you may be doing, to support easy implementation of JSON.